# How can i populate a combo box with data from an access database and use it to filter a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a page with a combo box and a datagrid. I have a countries database connected to the datagrid that loads the information from the database and populates the datagrid accordingly. i want to be able to use a combo box to filter the datagrid and just show the information about the country chosen. Is this possible?? Thanks

XAML CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="369" Width="749">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="grid1" ColumnWidth="SizeToCells" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="270" Width="721"/>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.CS:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadgrid();
        }

        private void loadgrid()
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [Country]";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grid1.ItemsSource = rd;

        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a hint, make an attempt then come back with specific questions or errrors: Add an OleDbParameter to the command that is the Country id. Fill your combobox with countries. On selection changed of the combobox call `loadgrid()` again and set the parameter value to the combobox selected value.

Comment: i am new to wpf so don't know much, what kind of parameter do i need to insert and where?

Comment: read up on ADO.Net and Google `OleDbParameter`. You will be tempted to concatenate strings together to build the SQL but don't, it is insecure and bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the CollectionViewSource (here are links: [How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html), [Working with CollectionView in WPF(Filter,Sort, Group, Navigate)](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html)) as the ItemsSource of the DataGrid and when the combobox value is changed, change the filter of that CollectionViewSource.

I'll glad to help if you will have a coding problems.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to populate the Country Combobox. `CmbCountry.ItemsSource = tableRows;` If your table has a Name column, then you will show this name in ComboBox.

   ```
   <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ...>
   ```
2. Then you need to know user's selection. Handle `SelectionChanged event` of ComboBox, and get user's choice using `CmbCountry.SelectedValue`. Note: This event is fired when you bind your ComoboBox ie; during Loading. So, check for null value too.
3. Now, using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.ItemsSource)`, get the `CollectionView`, and apply `Filter predicate`.

And slowly learn about Binding which is the cornerstone of WPF.

[CollectionViewSource tutorial](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html)

[How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072(v=vs.95).aspx)

[DataBinding tutorial](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html)

Comment: im getting an error saying 'tableRows' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: @abr I gave you an example, instead of tableRows, try using rd.

Comment: i also spent some time reading the 'everything you want to know' page but i'm just getting confused with the filter predicate function. i currently have the combo box displaying no data but a list of empty rows